# (Online) Hebrew Babylonian Talmud

Tags: product-recommendation, hebrew, internet, translation, talmud-bavli

I sometimes need to show things from Gemorra for someone who knows both Modern Hebrew and Lashon Hakodesh, but not Aramaic.

I do not need inserted explanation, like the Hebrew ArtScroll or Mesivta, just the Aramaic translated to its equivalent Hebrew. Like Soncino, but in Hebrew/Lashon Hakodesh.

Are there any such translations?

Are any available online?

Comment: There is a Hebrew ArtScroll also.

Comment: @Scimonster. See OP: "I do not need an explanation, like ArtScroll"

Comment: I saw that, i just left a comment about it in case it would be helpful.

Comment: IINM the ArtScroll includes the plain translation as boldfaced text within it's running commentary. (I know its English edition does.) If so, that answers the question. cc @Scimonster

Comment: I think all the explained etc. editions translate the text first. I was asking for such a text without interruptions. I'll edit.

Comment: The Steinsaltz Bavli was originally published in Modern Hebrew (along with the original text), but I don't know if you can find it online.

Comment: If Hebrew Artscroll isn't your thing you can use the Oz V'hadar Mesivta.

Comment: If you know both Lashon Kodesh and Modern Hebrew, you should be able to read Shas fairly well with some help on strictly Aramaic terms.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be such a publication - and you can see the Tractate on Bava Metzia [here](http://www.otzar.org/wotzar/book.aspx?158939). I can't figure out how to get to the other volumes, if they exist.

It was written by R' Nisim Binyamin Ochana, and printed in Port Sa'id in 1929